# Connecting to a 32-bit Oracle database from Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: database, windows, oracle, client

If this question has already been answered (which upon my research it has not), forgive me.

My question is, if I am running Windows 7 64-bit Professional and am trying to connect to a 32-bit Oracle 10g database on one of my local servers,

- a) Should I be connecting to it with a 32 or 64 bit version of Oracle
  client?
- b) Should there be any additional configuration steps
  after installing the client, to make the connection to the database?

I still have a pre-configured TNSNAMES.ORA file from when Windows XP 32-bit was the norm.

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: To connect to a 32 bit Oracle Server, use a 32 bit Oracle Client. Just in case it is necessary, both 32 and 64 bit client versions can be installed in parallel.

Comment: @ThomasTschernich Using a 32bit client should not be necessary. 64bit clients work just fine with 32bit servers.

Answer (score 0):

You say the Oracle Server is running on a 32-bit machine on a computer over your network. In this case, there should not be much of a problem.

Make sure of the following before you try connecting:

1. The listener on the Oracle Server is up and running.
2. The Oracle Server is not hiding behind a firewall. The port number for Oracle is usually 1521. Confirm before connecting.
3. You have installed Oracle SQL Developer or Toad or a similar database client on your machine. Make sure it has installed properly and it is up and running.

When you have all that handy, you can just create a new connection in SQL Developer or Toad, filling in the following details:

1. Username / Schema name
2. Password
3. Service name / SID
4. Oracle Server's IP address
5. Port number, usually 1521.